# DbContext Not Found or A relational store has been configured without specifying either the DbConnection or connection string to use

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

when using Entity Framework Commands ("7.0.0-beta1").

when running

k ef migration add InitialCreate

i'm getting errors.

[Solution]

i try to move my Class File (where DbContext is created) to main project from separate class library and everything working as expected.

so the real problem is when using DbContext in separate Class Library.

my dbcontext file

```
public class DbTables : DbContext
{

    public DbSet<class_name> class_name_alias { get; set; }

    private static bool _created = false;

    public DbTables()
    {
        if (_created)
        {
            Database.AsRelational().ApplyMigrations();
            _created = true;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptions options)
    {
        options.UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=app_db;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }

}
```

Comment: What's the errors you get ? I tried with your source code and didn't get error, you probably forgot a dependency

Comment: @aguafrommars 

1. DbContext Not Found 

2. A relational store has been configured without specifying either the DbConnection or connection string to use

regarding dependency, i copied exact code in separate library added dependency (in project.json) and also updated global.json to include class libraries from specific folders. there is no issue in resolving dependency.

Comment: Take a look [there](https://github.com/aguacongas/chatle/tree/master/test/DbContextTest) I copied your code in this test project and sucessfuly generate migration

Comment: When you get a DbContext not found, it's because you are running EF tool in the wrong project I guess. I mean, the project you run the EF command doesn't contain DbContext.

Comment: i'm running k ef commands on main project.

Comment: try moving Class1.cs file into a separate class library. see if it still works.

Comment: do you mean having a class representing a table in a class library and the db context in an other class library ?

Comment: yes. add that class library as dependency on main asp.net project.

Comment: Ok, I understand where is your mistake: The EF command declaration must be in project.json of the class library where the db context reside. If you move the db context from web project to a class library, you need to declare the ef command in this class library

Comment: the reason of that not working: 

We currently only call Startup.ConfigureServices() if it's in the same project as the DbContext. The default constructor of DbTables is preventing things from working without Startup.


https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/1352#issuecomment-68804565

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a DBContext in a class library, to create migration you have to declare the ef command in the project.json of this class library. and run the k ef commmand for this project.

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "dependencies": {
        "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta1",
        "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta1" 
    },
    "commands": {
        "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
    },
    "frameworks" : {
        "aspnet50" : { 
            "dependencies": {
            }
        },
        "aspnetcore50" : { 
            "dependencies": {
                "System.Runtime": "4.0.20-beta-22231"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You must override the on OnConfiguring method to set up a connection string

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptions options)
{
    options.UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=app_db;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False");
}
```